# photo uploading in php under centos platform

Tags: php, apache, centos

While loading the photo using the code

```
if (file_exists($DocRoot. $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
 { 
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source 
                                             path of the file in a variable 
                $image_name = $_SESSION['d']; 
                $targetPath = $DocRoot.$image_name; // Target path where 
                                                       file is to be stored
                move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file 

            }else{ 
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
                $image_name = $_SESSION['d']; 
                 // Storing source path of the file in a variable 
                $targetPath = $DocRoot.$image_name; // Target path where 
                                                       file is to be stored

         move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded 
                                                            file
```

the following error occurs:

Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpihV9Ar' to '/var/www/html/test963853/q1/cas/upload/4442910001.jpg' [file] => /var/www/html/test963853/q1/cas/stage1_1.php [line] => 1960 ) /var/www/html/test963853/q1/cas/upload/4442910001.jpg

***Experts state that there would be some problem with httpd.conf. What modification must be carried out in httpd.conf? Please suggest. Thank you in advance.***

Comment: Contact to your service provider. He help you.

Comment: Is your target directory write-able by the apache process ?

Comment: Definitely not an Apache misconfiguration. Please define "Experts"

Comment: I mean "Experts" as the persons who have better knowledge in php and centos

Comment: Target directory is writable only. Even then this error is reported during execution